# PSM1 not running cmdlets or functions when imported

Tags: powershell

I have a PSM1 file which has several functions relating to Azure and Azure AD. When imported, I'd like the module to run Get-AzContext to list the user's information. However, this cmdlet is not being run when imported despite not being in a function. Even when placing it in a function and calling the function in the module, it does not run. Once the module is imported, I'm able to call the function normally and it runs fine, it just does not run when importing.

In Test.psm1:

```
Get-AzContext
Write-Host 'test'
```

In test.psd1, test.psm1 is listed as the root module.

`ipmo test.psd1`

When importing, all it prints is `test` and not the results of Get-AzContext.

Comment: Show us your code. As described in https://stackoverflow.com/help, please provide an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original post to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not making sense. Are you looking to retrieve information from a function or module, if so provide the script your using, otherwise its hard to offer any assistance to you.

The Get-AzContext cmdlet gets the current metadata used to authenticate Azure Resource Manager requests. This cmdlet gets the Active Directory account, Active Directory tenant, Azure subscription, and the targeted Azure environment. Azure Resource Manager cmdlets use these settings by default when making Azure Resource Manager requests. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-6.6.0

```
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzContext

Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
```